# X-editable increase textarea cols size

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, x-editable

i have a problem in X-editable bootstrap 3 textarea, need to change cols and row size

```
$('.editable_textarea').editable({
       cancel: "Cancel",
       submit: "Save",
       type: "textarea",
       cols: "55"
});
```

While running it takes only the default value, not our value for cols, and rows. Have any suggestion?
Thanks in advance

Comment: cols is not part of the api.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use shown event of bootstrap editable like this:

```
$(".editable_textarea").on("shown", function (element, test) {
    $(test.input.$input[0]).attr("cols", "55")            
});
```